# Split and re-concatenate a string

Tags: r, string

I am trying to get the host of an IP address from a list of strings.

```
ips <- c('140.112.204.42', '132.212.14.139', '31.2.47.93', '7.112.221.238')
```

I want to get the first 2 digits from the ips. output:

```
ips <- c('140.112', '132.212', '31.2', '7.112')
```

This is the code that I wrote to convert them:

```
cat(unlist(strsplit(ips, "\\.", fixed = FALSE))[1:2], sep = ".")
```

When I check the type of individual ips in the end I get something like this:

```
140.112 NULL
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. If you have some other ideas completely different from this that is completely fine too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sub`:

```
ips <- c('140.112.204.42', '132.212.14.139', '31.2.47.93', '7.112.221.238')

sub('\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$', '', ips)
# [1] "140.112" "132.212" "31.2"    "7.112"
```

With `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(ips, '^\\d+\\.\\d+')
# [1] "140.112" "132.212" "31.2"    "7.112"
```

With `strsplit` + `sapply`:

```
sapply(strsplit(ips, '\\.'), function(x) paste(x[1:2], collapse = '.'))
# [1] "140.112" "132.212" "31.2"    "7.112"
```

With `read.table` + `apply`:

```
apply(read.table(textConnection(ips), sep='.')[1:2], 1, paste, collapse = '.')
#[1] "140.112" "132.212" "31.2"    "7.112"
```

**Notes:**

1. `sub('\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$', '', ips)`:

   i. `\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$` matches a literal dot, a digit one or more times, a literal dot again, and a digit one or more times **at the end of the string**

   ii. `sub` **removes** the above match from the string
2. `str_extract(ips, '^\\d+\\.\\d+')`:

   i. `^\\d+\\.\\d+` matches a digit one or more times, a literal dot and a digit one or more times **in the beginning of the string**

   ii. `str_extract` **extracts** the above match from the string
3. `sapply(strsplit(ips, '\\.'), function(x) paste(x[1:2], collapse = '.'))`:

   i. `strsplit(ips, '\\.')` splits each `ip` using a literal dot as the delimiter. This returns a list of vectors after the split

   ii. With `sapply`, `paste(x[1:2], collapse = '.')` is applied to every element of the list, thus taking only the first two numbers from each vector, and collapsing them with a dot as the separator. `sapply` then coerces the list to a vector, thus returning a vector of the desired ips.
4. `apply(read.table(textConnection(ips), sep='.')[1:2], 1, paste, collapse = '.')`:

   i. `read.table(textConnection(ips), sep='.')[1:2]` treats `ips` as text input and reads it in with dot as a delimiter. Only taking the first two columns.

   ii. `apply` enables `paste` to be operated on each row, and collapses with a dot.

Comment: with the `read.table` you do not need `apply` you can use `do.call(paste,c(sep='.',read.table(textConnection(ips), sep='.')[1:2]))`

Comment: Witha lager data, i believe do.call will outdo apply

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
gsub("([0-9]+.[0-9]+)(.*)","\\1",ips)
```

***Explanation:*** Using `gsub` function and putting regex there to match digits then DOT then digits in memory's 1st place holder and keeping `.*` everything after it in 2nd place holder of memory. Then substituting these with `\\1` with first regex's value which will be first 2 fields.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is the following:

```
vapply(strsplit(ips, ".", fixed = TRUE), 
       function(x) paste(x[1:2], collapse = "."), 
       character(1L))
```

- `vapply` applies `function(x)` to each element of the output of `strsplit`
- `strsplit` produces a list where each element of the list is the components of the IP addresses separated by `"."`; setting `fixed = TRUE` requests to split using the exact value of the splitting string (i.e., `"."`), not using regex
- `function(x)` takes the first two elements (`x[1:2]`) of each item coming out of `strsplit` and `paste`s them together, seperated by `"."`
- `character(1L)` tells `vapply` that each element of the output (i.e., returned from `function(x)` should be a string of length 1.

Edit: @useR posted this solution right before me (using `sapply`).

Answer (score 1):

`substr` is vectorised on the stop argument, so you can use this with a vector of positions before the second dot. `regexpr` gives the positions of the first match, so if you `sub` out the first one you can match on the second - which will be conveniently one before it's true position as needed (since you removed the first one).

```
substr(ips,1,regexpr("\\.",sub("\\.","",ips)))
[1] "140.112" "132.212" "31.2"    "7.112"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the ip addresses to numeric_version class and then format using this base R one-liner that employs no regular expressions:

```
format(numeric_version(ips)[, 1:2])
[1] "140.112" "132.212" "31.2"    "7.112"
```